# Logo margin is clickable

Tags: css, image

I want my logo be aligned to center and that be clickable outside the margins without html `img` tag - with css `background-image` or something that remove right click > view image.

http://jsfiddle.net/qhU5u/

Thanks.

**Solved**

Comment: It looks like it already does that to me

Comment: Inspect any decent site's logo to see how it's done. Try stackoverflow itself.

Comment: Why do you want to "remove right click > view image"? That won't stop people being able to save your logo (in fact, there's *no* way to stop that)

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to SO! If you've found a solution on your own, and no existing answer satisfies your requirements, please consider adding your own answer with the solution and marking that as accepted. That will greatly help anyone who has the same problem. =)

Comment: It's also considered polite to upvote any answer that _contributed_ and was _helpful_ to you. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really use an `img` tag. However if you don't want to for some reason:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhU5u/1/

I've completely removed the div and just used tha `a` tag to display the logo.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `img` element. This is far better for accessibility purposes.

For example, if someone is viewing your page without the CSS enabled, they will be able to see your logo if it is an `img`, but not if it is a `background-image`.

---

However, if you wish to use a `background-image`, I would recommend using a `div` with a fixed height and width which matches your image.

Then, place an `a` element inside the `div` giving this the same dimensions as the `div`.

Your way of nesting `div` inside an `a` is invalid HTML.

See Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qhU5u/2/

Comment: @PeeHaa placing a block element inside an inline element is valid HTML5? Please provide a reference

Comment: @Curt Sure one sec let me find the link

Comment: @Curt From [the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-a-element) (still not a standard though I know): "The a element may be wrapped around entire paragraphs, lists, tables, and so forth, even entire sections, so long as there is no interactive content within (e.g. buttons or other links).".

Comment: @PeeHaa Cheers! I wasn't aware of that. So this is just `a` elements then, not any inline element in general?

Answer (score 0):

try this example and see if it's what you're looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhU5u/8/

Comment: We wanted the logo margins not be clickable.
The problem is now solved, thanks.

Comment: Ah. From your initial question I read it that they were to be clickable. Just me mis-understanding your English. Glad you got a solution.